# Polymer and three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, polymer-1.0, nw.js

I´m  trying run three.js demo http://jsfiddle.net/hfj7gm6t/ into my polymer app but the app show an error:

> com-model-viewer.html:33 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'myview' of undefined

```
<link rel='import' href='../../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html'>
<dom-module id='com-model-viewer'>
<template>
<ul id='myview'>
</ul>
</template>
<script>
Polymer({
is:'com-model-viewer',
ready: function(){
  console.log(this);
  var camera, scene, renderer;
  var geometry, material, mesh;

  init();
  animate();

  function init(){

    console.log();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
    camera.position.z = 1000;
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(200, 200, 200);
    material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: 0xff0000,
      wireframe: true
    });
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(mesh);
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    Polymer.dom( this.$.myview ).appendChild(node);
  }

  function animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
    mesh.rotation.y += 0.02;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
}
});
</script>
<script src='../../../node_modules/three/three.min.js'></script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

im guessing that the `this` in your function `init` is not what you are looking for. `this` point to the function but not the polymer object.
try passing the original `this` variable into `init` or just rewrite `init` into es6 arrows function.

Comment: Yeah, the first option fix the problem